# <li> in center of page

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="site">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://roblox.com/Orinthian-Soldier-item?id=111514918&rbxp=61629949">Orinthian Soldier</a></li>
<li><a href="http://roblox.com/Sk8r-Boi-item?id=16101707&rbxp=61629949">Sk8r Boi</a></li>
<li><a href="http://roblox.com/Tokyokhaos-Super-Happy-Fun-Monkey-Companion-item?id=15857967&rbxp=61629949">Tokyokhaos Super Happy Fun Monkey Companion</a></li>
<li><a href="http://web.roblox.com/Dangerface-item?id=44561190&rbxp=61629949">Dangerface</a></li>
<li><a href="http://web.roblox.com/Captain-of-the-Pikemen-item?id=52556526&rbxp=61629949">Captain of the Pikemen</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#site {
 background: #fff;
 max-width: 1075px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-right: 120px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
 padding: 2px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}

#site p {
 text-align: left;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

#site h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

#site h2 {
 text-align: left;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

#site h3 {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 text-align: left;
}
```

The problem is that the text from the `<li>` tags are at the center of the page; how do I resolve this? http://prntscr.com/6y5c3j

Many thanks.

Comment: Relevant CSS would be nice. What are the ul & li rules? Betting there is some text-align stuff in there..

Comment: seems to be fine in https://jsfiddle.net/2uzejv3s/

Comment: I don't have any rules for ul and li.

Comment: Where do you expect them to be?

Comment: The text is meant to be next to the dots, not in the center.

Comment: Despite not being able to verify your problem, have you tried looking for a CSS rule acting on the `<li>` elements? Have you tried something like `li{text-align:left;}`?

Comment: Also it could be a caching problem. Maybe you have removed the rule that has been centering your list items but the browser still displays them centered. You can reload the page with cleared cache by pressing `Ctrl + F5`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code, nothing wrong in your code.
http://tinypic.com/r/4uyvwk/8

Maybe that centered `<li>` tag is because of your other css?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in three major browsers and the list items were all displayed correctly on the left side, not the center.  Try using a CSS reset at the start of your CSS file.  This may resolve the problem.  Below is one provided by Eric Myers.  Here is the link as well for reference.
[CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
  /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```